# Accessing FTP Server using a specific IP Address

Tags: ftp, download, ftp-server

I want to access a FTP Server, that is firewall protected meaning only IP addresses that have been added to the safe list may access the FTP file.

And The IP address of my website has been added to the safe list of the firewall.

I am using Filezilla to connect to it, but it is not allowing me to connect to the FTP server since my PC has a different IP.

Please suggest me a way to connect to the FTP server.

Thanks In advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ssh/telnet into your host, then you could use the command line ftp.
Another option is to use a web-based ftp client that is installed on your web server (such as http://www.phpwebftp.com/ if you have PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Run an ftp client on the allowed server; or, persuade the ftp admin to add your PC's IP address to the whitelist, and ensure and/or pray that it doesn't change (maybe pay your ISP extra for a static IP); or, use a proxy on an authorized server. The first option is definitely the most painless, assuming you have shell access to your web server (and if not, what sense does it make to have it on the authorized list?)

Some popular command-line clients you might find installed on the server include ftp (sic), ncftp, curl, wget, lynx, and w3m. The last two are actually terminal-based text-only web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access to your server, you could create a SSH-tunnel like this:

```
ssh user@example.org -L 21:127.0.0.1:21
```

then you can connect to the FTP-server using localhost:21 from your pc.

http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html